# Unintentionally adding keys to hash while iterating

Tags: perl, hashtable, key-value, autovivification

I'm iterating through a cache of a hash of hashes of latitude keys that point to key/value pairs of longitudes/cities. I'm trying to find approximate matches for latitudes/longitudes that are close enough to what's already been looked up and is in the hash.

I'm doing it like this

```
    foreach my $lat_key ( keys $lookup_cache_latlonhash ) {

        if ( ($lat > ($lat_key - .5)) && ($lat < ($lat_key + .5)) ) {

            foreach my $lon_key ( keys %{ $lookup_cache_latlonhash->{$lat_key}} ) {

                if ( ($lon > ($lon_key - .5)) && ($lon < ($lon_key + .5)) ) {

                    $country = $$lookup_cache_latlonhash{$lat_key}{$lon_key};
                    print "Approx match found: $lat_key $lon_key $country\n";
                    return $country;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The code works to find these lat/lon pairs within the range. However for each latitude it loops through using, when it does find it's in range (the first nested condition), it's adding it to the hash (presumably `keys %{ $goog_lookup_cache_latlonhash->{$lat_key}}`) which is not intended, adding useless/empty keys to the hash:

```
$VAR1 = {
      '37.59' => {},
      '37.84' => {},
      '37.86' => {},
      '37.42' => {
                   '126.44' => 'South Korea/Jung-gu'
                 },
      '37.92' => {},
      '37.81' => {},
      '38.06' => {
                   '-122.53' => 'America/Novato'
                 },
      '37.8' => {},
      '37.99' => {},
      '37.61' => {},
       ...
```

What's the clever, or at least sane, way to do this lookup? So I'm not unintentionally adding keys to the hash just by looking them up?

Comment: Note that allowing `keys` to work on a reference was decided to be a bad idea, and was removed from Perl v5.24. So `keys $lookup_cache_latlonhash` should be written as `keys %$lookup_cache_latlonhash`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're experiencing is [auto-vivification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autovivification).  It's a feature of Perl to make working with nested structures a little easier.

Any time an undefined value is dereferenced, perl will automatically create the object you're accessing.

```
use Data::Dumper; 
my $hash = {}; if ($hash->{'a'}) {} #No auto-vivification because you're just checking the value   
keys %{$hash->{'b'}}; #auto-vivification because you're acting on the value (getting the keys of it) $hash->{b} 
print Dumper($hash);
```

There are a couple of ways to avoid this -

1. Add `no autovivification` in the scope you want to avoid this
   functionality
2. Check to see if they item you're accessing is defined
   or exists (and is of the type you need)

I recommend the second one because it helps build the habit of checking your code for correct data structuring and makes debugging much easier.

```
foreach my $lat_key (keys $lookup_cache_latlonhash) {
    if (($lat > ($lat_key - .5)) 
        && ($lat < ($lat_key + .5)) 
        && ref($lookup_cache_latlonhash->{$lat_key}) eq 'HASH')  #expecting a hash here - undefined or any non-hash value will skip the foreach
    {
        foreach my $lon_key (keys %{ $lookup_cache_latlonhash->{$lat_key}}) {
            if (($lon > ($lon_key - .5)) && ($lon < ($lon_key + .5))) {
                $country = $$lookup_cache_latlonhash{$lat_key}{$lon_key};
                print "Approx match found: $lat_key $lon_key $country\n";
                return $country;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense and the sandwiched if between each foreach is clear - thorough answer. I'm wondering why `no autovivification` isn't invoked with `use strict` - it feels like it should be, no?

Comment: @ikebukuru - In my experience, autovivification is the desired behavior (or at least not-undesired) well over 90% of the time. It does surprise a lot of people the first time they encounter it, but it's extremely rare for it to do any harm beyond that.

Comment: I'm unclear why you think `keys %{ $lookup_cache_latlonhash->{$lat_key} }` will autovivify an element when this is inside a loop `for my $lat_key ( keys $lookup_cache_latlonhash )` so the element must already exist.

Comment: @Borodin indeed! That's why it had me scratching my head. Thanks for cleaning up my question's code for readability.

Comment: @ikebukuru: The only way I can see this happening with your own code is if you have the elements already existing but with a value of `undef`, which will also be autovivified. Is that possible? If not then the problem must exist elsewhere in your code. Check the hash both before and after the outer `for` loop.

Comment: @Borodin - I somehow missed that it was accessing keys of an element as it looped over it.  However, the description of the problem sounds like a classic explanation of auto-vivification.  There may be another location in the code that's causing the issue, but it does most likely boil down to auto-vivification.

Comment: @TrentonTrama it absolutely was an auto-vivification issue; before asking, I'd put in `my $size = keys $lookup_cache_latlonhash;` and was printing a Dumper of the hash and watching it grow upon every loop through. Found that with the `no autovivification` directive it worked, before implementing the cleaner solution that you recommended. Thanks!

Comment: @ikebukuru: I would still like to see this explained properly. Please can you give some example data that will display this behaviour with the code in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Put

```
no autovivification;
```

in scope.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [exists keyword](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) for this.

### Solution

```
use Data::Dumper;
$hash = {};
$hash{'alpha'} = 'yep';
$hash{'beta'} = 'this too';
if (exists $hash{'gamma'}) {
    print "Found gamma."
}
print Dumper(\%hash);
$hash{'gamma'} = 'added';
if (exists $hash{'gamma'}) {
    print "Gamma was updated.\n"
}
print Dumper(\%hash);
```

### Example Output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'beta' => 'this too',
          'alpha' => 'yep'
        };
Gamma was updated.
$VAR1 = {
          'gamma' => 'added',
          'beta' => 'this too',
          'alpha' => 'yep'
        };
```

Comment: This is completely unrelated to the code in the question.